# Automatic postback: Give error the variable name has already been declared

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, telerik

I'm trying to bind telerik autocomplete textbox from mssql database using `asp c#.net`.

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox AllowCustomEntry="true" ID="RadAutoCompleteBox2" runat="server" InputType="Text">
    <TextSettings SelectionMode="Single" />
</telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
```

And my .aspx.cs file's code is given below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {   
        SqlDataSource SqlDataSource1 = new SqlDataSource();
        SqlDataSource1.ID = "SqlDataSource1";
        this.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1);
        SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = "my connection";
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select citylocation from citylocationtbl where cityname=@cityname";
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@cityname", Request.QueryString["city"].ToString());
        RadAutoCompleteBox2.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
        RadAutoCompleteBox2.DataTextField = "citylocation";
        RadAutoCompleteBox2.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

When I remove Parameters, code working properly but in parameters line I'm still getting error.

> The variable name @cityname has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

I'm getting error because when I press any key telerik autosuggesbox automatically postback and bind data again and again.

Comment: By the title it looks like a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%22The%20variable%20name%22%20%22has%20already%20been%20declared%22%5bc%23%5d). But a simple `if (!IsPostBack)` should do the trick. Your problem is basicaly that you should do this code only the 1rst time the [Page Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#general_page_lifecycle_stages)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadCity(Request.QueryString["city"].ToString());
    }

}

protected void LoadCity(string _city)
{
    try
    {
        SqlDataSource SqlDataSource1 = new SqlDataSource();
        SqlDataSource1.ID = "SqlDataSource1";
        this.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1);
        SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = "my connection";
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select citylocation from citylocationtbl where cityname=@cityname";
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@cityname", _city);
        RadAutoCompleteBox2.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
        RadAutoCompleteBox2.DataTextField = "citylocation";
        RadAutoCompleteBox2.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

}
```